# Wordpress Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a standard page setup at `http://mysite.com/mypage/`

I'd like to setup a rewrite rule in my theme functions that takes any URLs such as:

`http://mysite.com/mypage/helloworld/`   <-- Currently shows "Not Found"

And translates it into:

`http://mysite.com/mypage/?var=helloworld`  <-- Currently shows the standard page

NOTE ADDED:

"helloworld" is an unknown variable value, so I want ALL "/mypage/" urls to rewrite back, for example:
`http://mysite.com/mypage/abc/`
`http://mysite.com/mypage/1231241/`
`http://mysite.com/mypage/sdfasfdadsf/`

Will all rewrite back to `http://mysite.com/mypage/?var={path}`

Comment: ís this just for /mypage/ or also for another urls?

Comment: Only for /mypage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question was modified, I modify my answer. This task is relatively easy, doable just with a single rewrite rule, which converts everything after /mypage/ string into a variable - I call it var. As this is added to query_vars via hook, is reachable via `global $wp_query; echo $wp_query->var;`.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'binda_query_vars' );
function binda_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'var';
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'binda_rewrite_rules' );
function binda_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {           
   $mypage_id = 4; //setup your 'mypage' ID
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(             
        'mypage/(.+?)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?page_id='.$mypage_id.'&var=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),        
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Comment: "helloword" is an unknown variable, please see note added to my question.

Comment: this completely changes the question

Comment: see modified answer above

Comment: Thanks!  It's worth noting that i had to remove the leading '/' for it to work: `$wp_rewrite->rules = array(             
        'mypage/(.+?)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?page_id='.$mypage_id.'&var=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),       
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;`

Comment: I'm sorry for that little issue. Wouldn't you mind to mark the answer as correct, please?

Comment: I've modified the answer in your proposed way.